# What's the observer in double slit experiment?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, double-slit-experiment, observers

I watched a video on youtube about double slit and it said that when we try to observe electrons it starts to act like a particle but what are these observers that they use? they're shooting one electron at a time so how can they detect them while they're moving in front of the observer?

Comment: Which Youtube video?

Comment: More on [observers in YDSE](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/double-slit-experiment+observers).

Comment: @Qmechanic this one: https://youtube.com/watch?v=TT-_uCLwKhQ

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An observer is you or someone looking at the electron. It can also be a detector or camera taking pictures etc. it is wrong to think that the mind of a conscious observer will cause  an observer effect. The thing is if you look at an electron as it's traveling through the slits you will affect it's a trajectory because you physically interfered with it. In order to see the electron photons need to interact with it and they will affect its path causing the overall interference pattern to be disturbed.

Comment: how close the observer should be?

Comment: Distance doesn't matter as long as you can observe.

Comment: Would a camera taking pictures actually be able to see moving electrons? What is an example of a detector in a real example of such an experiment?

Comment: @BT a device or instrument designed to detect the presence of a particular object or substance and to emit a signal in response. The problem with detecting electrons is you interfere with their trajectories.

Comment: You just defined "detector". I was curious what an example would be.

Comment: The simplest form of a detector is your eye. I detector can be any device that converts the photon or electron energy to an electronic signal so we can process the information. A Geiger counter does this or can be something as simple as photographic paper. Any of these detectors will directly interfere with the particles trajectory (by absorbing it) there for changing the overall interference pattern.

Comment: Won't photons interact with the electron anyway? Even if there's no observer?

Comment: @Mausy5043 Yes of course, an observer is not needed